# How to hide/remove particular area from top and bottom of image - GLControl

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, shader, opentk

I can display below image using opengl in my `glControl`. Is there any way to cut or hide particular area (say 50px from top and bottom) equally from both  bottom and top of `glControl`? Below is the code I have used to calculate the size of `glControl`. Can I achieve it by changing values on view port?

[image]

```cs
private void OpenGL_Size(GLControl glControl, VideoCaptureDevice videoSource)//always in portrait  mode

{
    decimal RateOfResolution = (decimal)videoSource.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Width / (decimal)videoSource.VideoResolution.FrameSize.Height;

    decimal screenHeightbyTwo = this._Screenheight / 2;             
    RateOfResolution = 1 / RateOfResolution;// portrait 
    openGLheight = Convert.ToInt32(screenHeightbyTwo);   // height is fixed; calculate the width
    openGLwidth = (Convert.ToInt32(RateOfResolution * screenHeightbyTwo));

    glControl.Width = openGLwidth;
    glControl.Height = openGLheight;
}

GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, glControl.Width, glControl.Height));
```

Shader code

```c
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;
void main ()
{ 
    vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture,vTexCoordIn);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: _"Can I achieve it by changing values on view port?"_ Did you tried it? If you change the ViewPort, your ratio will be changed. You should check the `glScissors` for this.

Comment: tried by  GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 50, glControl.Width, glControl.Height +(2 * 50))); but  it didnt crop the image

Comment: That's why the Scissors exists, it will crop the output without changing the scaling/centerpoint etc. The viewport doesn't clip anything. _(I learn this the hard way when implementing webvr, rendering side-by-side)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip a some parts of the texture, then you can use the [`discard`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Special_operations) keyword. This command causes the fragment's output values to be discarded and the fragments are not drawn at all.

```c
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D sTexture;
varying vec2 vTexCoordIn;

void main ()
{ 
    if (vTexCoordIn.y < 0.1 || vTexCoordIn.y > 0.9)
        discard;

    vec4 color = texture2D(sTexture, vTexCoordIn);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

If the height of the image and the height of the area which has to be discarded is given, then the condition is:

```c
float img_h_px  = 432.0; // height of the image in pixel
float area_h_px = 50.0;  // area height in pixel

float w = area_h_px/img_h_px;
if (vTexCoordIn.y < w || vTexCoordIn.y > (1.0-w))
    discard;
```

Comment: how can i convert a 50px to a range of vTexCoordIn ?

Comment: @user2431727 `vTexCoordIn.y` is in range [0.0, 1.0], so `vTexCoordIn.y*50` is in  range [0, 50]

Comment: so is this? , if (vTexCoordIn.y >  vTexCoordIn.y*50 || vTexCoordIn.y <1 - vTexCoordIn.y*50)
        discard;

Comment: @user2431727 No. What is the height of the bitmap? What is the height of the area which has to be discarded?

Comment: bitmap is 640*480, from calculation glcontrol is
324*432.  I want s to discard  50px from both top and bottom of glcontrol

Comment: @user2431727 See the answer.